# Open new (popup) window to answer Twilio call

Tags: javascript, jquery, twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm using the Twilio JavaScript SDK to place and receive calls in the browser.  As part of this I have a requirement to make and receive calls in a new popup window.  This is so that a user can continue browsing the site without disconnecting the call.

I have got this working for outgoing calls (a user clicks a number, and on the back of this I call `window.open` which initiates the call).

However for incoming calls, I'm attempting to do the following in the initiating browser window:

```
Twilio.Device.incoming(function (connection) {
    $('#callPopup').show();
    $('.js-answer-call').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var receiveCallWindow = window.open('/call/incoming', '', 'width=350,height=200');
        receiveCallWindow.connection = connection;
        $('#callPopup').hide();
    });
    $('.js-reject-call').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        connection.reject();
        $('#callPopup').hide();
    });
});
```

This passes the connection object to the popup window, and then the popup window runs the following code:

```
var connection = window.connection;
$(document).ready(function () {
    connection.accept();
});
```

This does answer the call, however the call context is still within the parent window and if a user navigates away from that page it will end the call.

I understand that I can achieve this via a master iframe containing just the call logic, with the main web app inside the frame, however I think that's a very messy implementation and want to avoid that.

Answer (score -1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your problem in this case is indeed that the call context is in the parent window. The only thing that comes to mind to me right now is to popup the call window when your user logs on and is prepared to answer calls and then initialise the [`Twilio.Device`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device) in the popup window.

You could still connect this popup window to the code for outbound calls too.

Does this help at all?

Comment: Yeh I understand what you mean, however I just hoped I could achieve this by a simple popup when someone calls.  I'll need to have a rethink about how to approach the problem

Comment: i have the same problem....actually i post a question about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55820638/twilio-js-sdk-i-want-to-answer-a-softphone-call-in-a-different-window